# Salt hydrolysis or buffer solution

Tags: acid-base

Whenever there a question comes to find the pH of the given solution, I always gets confused to identify the solution if it is a buffer solution or whether it will undergo salt hydrolysis .

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you could [edit] in a couple examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have just a salt left with either [or even both] of its ions coming from a weak acid/base, it is a case of SALT HYDROLYSIS. I mean to say no free acid or base is left.
e.g,
100 mL 0.1 N CH3COOH + 100 mL 0.1 N NaOH ---> 100 mL 0.05 N CH3COONa
This need to be solved by SALT HYDROLYSIS

While if you have a salt(from the same weak acid/base) + a weak acid or base present, i.e., both are present, it would be a case of BUFFER.

200 mL 0.1 N CH3COOH + 100 mL 0.1 N NaOH ---> 100 mL 0.033 N CH3COONa + 100 mL 0.033 N CH3COOH (left unreacted)
This need to be solved by BUFFER

Comment: Avoid answering questions with low votes.